# Ionic2 - using a starter by specifying a github url fails with "cannot read property"

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-cli

I am trying to use a starter template available via a git repository.

when I am applying the ionic start command as specified e. g. for the ionic super starter, I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\DemoUser\Development\steroidsProjects>ionic login
[OK] You are logged in!
C:\Users\DemoUser\Development\steroidsProjects>ionic start testapp https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-super.git --v2
TypeError: Cannot read property 'private' of undefined
    at inputs.filter (C:\Users\DemoUser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\@ionic\cli-utils\dist\lib\command\command.js:91:31)
    at Array.filter (native)
    at StartCommand.getCleanInputsForTelemetry (C:\Users\DemoUser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\@ionic\cli-utils\dist\lib\command\command.js:90:18)
    at StartCommand.<anonymous> (C:\Users\DemoUser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\@ionic\cli-utils\dist\lib\command\command.js:63:48)
    at next (native)
    at fulfilled (C:\Users\DemoUser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\@ionic\cli-utils\dist\lib\command\command.js:4:58)
```

Any Ideas what is going wrong here?

Already tried:

- deinstall/reinstall ionic
- update npm
- get a new version of nodejs (6.9.5)
- use nvm to manage versions of nodejs

My kit:

Windows 8.1 64Bit

```
ionic --version
3.0.0-beta7
npm --version
4.5.0
```

Comment: I also did npm cache clean and delete the whole npm and npm-cache directory structure ... reinstalling after that.

Comment: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-super/issues/88 I dont think it that is ported to ionic 3 properly.. maybe raise a github issue ?

Comment: Happens with any github hostes starter template. Not only super ...